# Release memory by gc() in silence

Tags: r, memory, garbage-collection

I am running R code in ubuntu and want to release some memory. After I remove (`rm()`) variables, I call `gc()`. It seems it works. But how can make it work in silence (i.e. don't report the message). 
I tried to set `gcinfo(verbose=FALSE)`, but `gc()` still reports the message.

```
gcinfo(verbose=FALSE)
# [1] FALSE
gc()
#             used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
# Ncells    256641  13.8     467875   25.0    350000   18.7
# Vcells 103826620 792.2  287406824 2192.8 560264647 4274.5
```

Answer (score 10):

The `invisible()` function is useful for this.  One way would be to write a little `gc()` wrapper function of your own that without any arguments returns `gc()` invisibly.

```
gcQuiet <- function(quiet = TRUE, ...) {
    if(quiet) invisible(gc()) else gc(...)
}

gcQuiet()        ## runs gc() invisibly

gcQuiet(FALSE)
#          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
# Ncells 283808 15.2     531268 28.4   407500 21.8
# Vcells 505412  3.9    1031040  7.9   896071  6.9

gcQuiet(FALSE, verbose=TRUE)
# Garbage collection 26 = 12+1+13 (level 2) ... 
# 15.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (53%)
# 3.9 Mbytes of vectors used (49%)
#          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
# Ncells 283813 15.2     531268 28.4   407500 21.8
# Vcells 505412  3.9    1031040  7.9   896071  6.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty method that I use:

```
echo "gc()" > gc.R
```

Then you can just do this:

```
source("gc.R", echo=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is

```r
#assign the output to a variable 
a <- gc()
```